# Full-Calendar on rails 4: How do I save the dragged events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm aware that there is some pretty solid documentation on this gem. 
http://fullcalendar.io/.

With that being said I am a newb, and am pretty sure I'm still not even integrating this properly. Anyways, the existing code DOES work. However, I don't understand how to save the events. Right now, the ability to resize events and move events works fine. It is pulling the events from index.json.jbuilder. I want it to be able to drag/resize the events and save those changes. What do I need to add to be able to do this?

index.html.erb:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
      /*
        date store today date.
        d store today date.
        m store current month.
        y store current year.
      */
      var date = new Date();
      var d = date.getDate();
      var m = date.getMonth();
      var y = date.getFullYear();

      /*
        Initialize fullCalendar and store into variable.
        Why in variable?
        Because doing so we can use it inside other function.
        In order to modify its option later.
      */

      var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
      {
        /*
          header option will define our calendar header.
          left define what will be at left position in calendar
          center define what will be at center position in calendar
          right define what will be at right position in calendar
        */
        header:
        {
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        /*
          defaultView option used to define which view to show by default,
          for example we have used agendaWeek.
        */
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        /*
          selectable:true will enable user to select datetime slot
          selectHelper will add helpers for selectable.
        */
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        /*
          when user select timeslot this option code will execute.
          It has three arguments. Start,end and allDay.
          Start means starting time of event.
          End means ending time of event.
          allDay means if events is for entire day or not.
        */
        select: function(start, end, allDay)
        {
          /*
            after selection user will be promted for enter title for event.
          */
          var title = prompt('Event Title:');
          /*
            if title is enterd calendar will add title and event into fullCalendar.
          */
          if (title)
          {
            calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
              {
                title: title,
                start: start,
                end: end,
                allDay: allDay
              },
              true // make the event "stick"
            );
          }
          calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        },
        /*
          editable: true allow user to edit events.
        */
        editable: true,
        /*
          events is the main option for calendar.
          for demo we have added predefined events in json object.
        */
              events: '/events.json',

      });

    });

  </script>
<div id='calendar'></div>

<h1>Listing Events</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Start time</th>
      <th>End time</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @events.each do |event| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= event.title %></td>
        <td><%= event.description %></td>
        <td><%= event.start_time %></td>
        <td><%= event.end_time %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', event %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_event_path(event) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', event, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Event', new_event_path %>
```